# conjugate of S5

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that the elements $g:=(123)(45)$ and $h := (235)(14)$ are conjugate in $S_5$.

Just wanted to know if my work is semi on the right track, so far:
$5!/5 = 24$ and $\vert \{ \sigma i : i ∈ Z\}\vert = 5 = \vert S_5\vert /24).$

Therefore  if $g^{−1}\sigma g = \tau$ then $g = (1 2 3)(4 5)h$ for some $h$ in the normalizer of $\sigma$

Comment: What is $\{\sigma i : i \in Z\}$? Why 24?

Comment: Try using the fact that $\sigma(a_1\ a_2\ \dots\ a_k)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1)\ \sigma(a_2)\ \dots\ \sigma(a_k))$...